# How to Convert URLField in a Image on Django

Tags: python, django

I have kept the url of an image on a URLField, such that as well as I can display the image on the model of my home page and not the string of the URL, I can not convert that direction, "www.google.es/images/car "in an image of a car?

models.py

```
Photo class (models.Model):
     name = models.CharField (max_length = 150)
     url = models.URLField ()
     __unicode def __ (self): # 0 parameters
         return self.name
```

views.py

```
def home (request):
     photos = Photo.objects.all ()
     html = '<ul>'
     for photo in photos:
         html + = '<li>' + photo.url + '</ li>'
     html + = '</ ul>'
     return HttpResponse (html)
```

How could i convert in a imagen `photo.url` into a Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert the string into image however you can use the url in `src` attribute inside `<img>` tag

```
for photo in photos:
     html + = '<li><img src="' + photo.url + '"></ li>'
```

Remember that you are generating HTML for the website not rendering it's content

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
def home (request):
     photos = Photo.objects.all ()
     html = '<ul>'
     for photo in photos:
         html + = '<li><img src="{}"><li>'.format(photo.url)
     html + = '</ ul>'
     return HttpResponse (html)
```

Perhaps even better, again relying on formatting instead of string concatenation:

```
def home (request):
     photos = Photo.objects.all ()
     html = '<ul>{}</ul>'
     html_photos = []
     for photo in photos:
         html_photos.append('<li><img src="{}"><li>'.format(photo.url))
     html = html.format("\n".join(html_photos))
     return HttpResponse (html)
```

Comment: If i put into a html = html.format("\nThis is the imagen " + photo + .join(html_photos))

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code you provided will not do what you want.